# Webkit scrolling container no longer respects bottom margin when contents change

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm seeing a weird bug in Chrome (but not Firefox) with a web app with an instant messaging-style view. The input box is absolutely positioned at the bottom of the page and has height `X` while the scrolling pane of messages is absolutely positioned with `bottom: X` such that the bottom of the pane lines up with the input box.

Inside the message pane there are many messages. Each of these have an absolutely positioned child. When the contents of one of these inner children changes (say, with jQuery's `.html()`) the bottom margin of the bottom message becomes ignored.

[Here's a minimal jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPqUQ/3/). It scrolls the message pane to the bottom for you. Click the button, and you'll see that the margin on the bottom message box is no longer respected when determining how to size the message pane (`#a`).

My workaround is to remove the absolutely positioned children. In the jsfiddle, you can change the `position: absolute` to `float: left` on `#inner` and see that the bug no longer manifests. I'm curious why this problem is happening, though.

Comment: This bug is also present on Safari 6.0.2. However, it appears to be fixed in Chrome 26 (but not 25 or previous versions). Perhaps it's a Webkit bug that was rolled into Chrome 26. I couldn't identify this issue exactly in Webkit bugzilla.

Comment: I've ran into this issue as well. Glad to see it appears to be fixed in the latest WebKit nightly (version "537+").

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed in the latest version, please use.